# linux openssl simple client non-blocking bio over already existing socket, buffer, and epoll abstraction

Tags: c++, openssl, network-programming, epoll

Is there simple example code that shows how to create a non-blocking network-based bio from scratch? I do not need to verify right now or renegotiate, just get data flowing back and forth first.

I'm trying to use openssl on top of an already existing abstraction of epoll, sockets, and buffers. I already have existing machinery for all of that and am trying to create a BIO over it, but I cannot for the life of me get it to work. I already have an established TCP connection, so I need to insert that into a source/sink bio and then do the handshake.

The current state is the dreaded scenario where SSL_connect returns -1, SSL_get_error returns 5 (syscall error), and errno reads SUCCESS. I have seen others have the same problem, but not a single answer.

The reason for doing this instead of just using a mem bio to shuttle bytes to back forth is because the rest of the stack is fairly well optimized, and I don't want to do the extra copying.

My first idea what just to implement a bio over the in and out buffers I already maintain, but I cannot get that work either. There are a lot questions floating around this site and others. Some have outdated answers, but most just don't have answers that work when they do have answers at all.

Comment: Using openssl has been a absolute miserable experience. Nothing is documented well enough to use. The BIO interface is a mess or abstraction violations. I wish there was something else, but there really isn't.

Comment: Not much argument there. 3.0 got better, but it is still a helluva learning curve, and super easy to get something subtle wrong. I've never had the misfortune of having to do what you're doing, so I'm not going to be any help, but just wanted you to know someone out there understands, and is rooting for you. Best of luck, mate.

Comment: Hmmm, or maybe you can hack around your `SSL_connect` problem.  Perhaps do that in a separate thread with the socket in blocking mode, then change it [back] to non-blocking mode before you start using it in earnest.  Still sounds fiddly though, and may not help since reading and writing might still fail.

Comment: You mean my second suggestion?  I don't think it's _that_ bad, and sometimes a man's gotta do what a man's gotta do, no?  And if you don't mind risking blocking your main thread on the rare occasions when `SSL_connect` takes a while to return, then you can call it from there instead.  Who's TC?

Comment: In fact, if `SSL_connect` simply doesn't work right with a non-blocking socket, you might not have a choice.  And just _why_ is it so hacky?  Seems pragmatic to me.  I'm not doubting your ability, just suggesting something you might not have thought of.

Comment: @PaulSanders Sorry didn't finish last comment. You do what you need to do lol. My point was if I'm having problems, others way in over their head. The rest of my networking stack is very similar - it should slide in - just another level in my on_read / on_connect chain. I make heavy use of spans to avoid copying and be cache efficient, each layer tells the layer below how much data it could consume. I have seen any sample code that fully puts the connect in the epoll loop itself. I can't block ever either. There is a chance OpenSSL is just broken this way. I hope not.

Answer (score 1):

Well, interesting.  I would have made this a comment but it's too long.

I think this might boil down to the version of OpenSSL you are using.  I took my existing blocking socket implementation and did this (sorry, it's a bit quick and dirty and doesn't bother to clear the error stack as it should, but that doesn't seem to be causing a problem.  The busy loop is intentional, to hammer OpenSSL as hard as possible, but I also tried it with a short sleep and the result was the same):

```
u_long non_blocking = 1;
int ioctl_err = ioctlsocket (skt, FIONBIO, &non_blocking);
assert (ioctl_err == 0);
int connect_result = 0;
int connect_err = 0;

for ( ; ; )
{
    connect_result = SSL_connect (ssl);
    if (connect_result >= 0)
        break;

    connect_err = SSL_get_error (ssl, connect_result);
    if (connect_err != SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ && connect_err != SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE)
        break;                  // I put a breakpoint here; it was never hit
}

u_long non_blocking = 0;        // so that the rest of my code still works
ioctl_err = ioctlsocket (skt, FIONBIO, &non_blocking);

if (connect_result <= 0)        // this never happened either
    do_something_appropriate ();

// Various (synchronous) calls to `SSL_read` and `SSL_write`, these all worked fine
```

Now I know this isn't exactly what you are doing, but from OpenSSL's point of view that shouldn't matter.  So, for me, I can get it to work.

Testing environment:

- Windows (sorry!)
- OpenSSL 3.0.1 (which, if not the latest, is not far off)

**tl;dr** If you're using the OpenSSL libraries that came with your Linux installation, it might be time to move on.  Plus, if you build it from source you can build it with debug info, which might come in handy some time (I've actually built two versions for exactly this reason - one optimised and one not).

So that's it.  HTH.  Looks like you might be OK after all.

---

PS: I'm obviously not doing anything with BIOs here, and maybe your problem lies there instead.  If so, we need some self-contained sample code using those which exhibits the problems you are having.  Then, perhaps, someone can suggest a solution.

Comment: Ubuntu 21.10 ships with 1.1.1l (one spot one spot one ell). Let me try to upgrade to the 3.x stuff.

Comment: I do not want to get too far ahead of myself, bc I've been burned too many times in the last week with this, but I think the change to 3.0 worked. Another huge issue is that the cmake files with openssl don't find anything except those the system installed one so it just kept using 1.1.1 even though it would report finding 3.0. OpenSSL is just a monster of problems. I never want to touch this thing again. I had to straight hard code the library paths lol.

Comment: Excellent.  Please feel to upvote me.  For various reasons, I actually build it as a static library.  There's less to go wrong then.

Comment: I hope it does. After some reading last night, I'm not even sure it is possible to redefine the BIOs the way I want. One of the devs said if you use a memory bio you can't use the BIO->ptr since the code uses it to see where you are in the buffer. So I need to use  a SOURCE SINK bio and set the nbio (non-block) flag, and this is singnificantly more involved. In the end the BIO abstractions knows too much about other things going on.

Comment: Could be.  The relevant code looks to be in `bss_mem.c`.  I can't really comment further since I've never done anything with BIOs.  But, personally, I'd get it all working first, then optimise afterwards if necessary.  You might find, for example, that the cost of encrypting and decrypting dwarfs the cost of any extra copies anyway.

Comment: I found my bug in while trying the mem bio. When ssl reports want read, it really means send what I just gave you, so the correct response to want read (and basically anyting) is to write what is in the outbound bio then go into epoll.

Comment: OK, good.  Glad you're up and running.

Answer (score -2):

Define BIO method:

- BIO_meth_new
- BIO_meth_set_write_ex
- BIO_meth_set_read_ex
- BIO_meth_set_ctrl
- BIO_meth_free

Create BIO:

- BIO_new
- BIO_set_data
- BIO_free

Associate BIO with SSL:

- SSL_set_bio

Comment: I think the OP knows all that.  But he can't get it to work.

Comment: And this exemplifies what is wrong with OpemSSL - a list of functions with a zero guides on how to implement a minimal working connection. E.g., what messages does BIO_metho_set_ctrl need to implement and what are the correct return values? What are the semantics? For those two questions , the aswer changes for each control messages  and if you are non-blocking. It ever seems that if I call ERR_get_error too man times, it returns nonsensical values.

Comment: Why do you use stackoverflow to bash OpenSSL? Use Github issues for that. :P

Comment: I think you only need to implement BIO_CTRL_FLUSH by returning 1 when you wrap a memory buffer.

Comment: @pindumb I think I need to do a SOURCE_SINK bio. One of the devs on a post on their list said the memory bios use the BIO->ptr to do some checks on if it has more data. I'm basically a buffered socket at some level just with 2 buffers each way (1 in and 2 for out bio) . I'm not even sure this is possible.

Comment: @JasonN Yes i thought you want to implement your own BIO, similar to mem bio but where you provide your own read and write buffer from outside.